# To check which resource is being accessed by which process

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, selinux, resources

I have some process running on my system. I need to list out which of the process at a moment has acquired/is using one or more of these in my system:

1. Ethernet
2. Camera
3. USB
4. Bluetooth
5. WiFi
6. File System

etc.

Is there a way to find this out ?

Platform : Ubuntu/Fedora (Allowed to have SELinux as well if required to implement the above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a combination of `lsof` (to find out which process opened which file or port) and `strace` (to attach to and follow a process's system calls). Use the man pages for each to find out how to use them in your case

Comment: Does it help? Or do you need more information?